# asp-action and Html.ActionLink not working in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Edit: After couple computer restarts, it started working now. **Very weird!**
Thank you everyone for their time. :)

After going through few answers from SO, I'm still unable to make it work.

I'm just following an example out of a book: `Pro ASP.NET Core 3` by Adam Freeman.

Started with a simple .NET core mvc app with the command line:

```
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 3.1.100 --output PartyInvites
dotnet new mvc --no-https --output PartyInvites --framework netcoreapp3.1
```

The controller setup:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult RsvpForm()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The `Index.cshtml` has that simple anchor tag:

```
<a asp-action="RsvpForm">RSVP Now</a>
```

The full file with the project structure:
[image]
I've seen in many answers that we need to use this:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

but it looks like I already have that in my `_ViewImports.cshtml` which looks like this:

```
@using PartyInvites
@using PartyInvites.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

I even tried the good ol' action link method, but that didn't work either:

```
@Html.ActionLink("RSVP Now", "RsvpForm", "Home", new object { }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

While running the app, I never see the link:
[image]

The link is not even present in the rendered HTML:
[image]

What could I be doing wrong here?
Thank you for your time!

PS: I'm on `Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac` (macOs Catalina v 10.15.7).

If you'd like to look at the whole project, I've pushed it on Github as well:

https://github.com/affableashish/party-invites

Comment: Make sure `_ViewImports.cshtml` is in right place.

Comment: Is `asp-action` highlighted in Visual Studio? I'd imagine it's not, and that you need to include `@addTagHelper` because you're killing the `Layout`, but I might be wrong

Comment: Have you tried adding asp-controller"ControllerName"?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I added a screenshot that shows the project structure and also shows that the `asp-action` is highlighted.

Comment: I justr created a new project from the template and copied what you're showing here, and I cannot reproduce, the link works fine. Perhaps you can do the same on a new solution and see where is the difference?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I created a new project again and still can't create a link :( . Looks like `@Html.ActionLink` doesn't work either. I updated the question again.

Comment: Can you update with the entire rendered HTML?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I just put up the rendered HTML in the question. Looks like the link is not even rendered.

Comment: Could you please share your Startup.cs?

Comment: @Rena Sure I can. And I put the link to the whole project in the question now. The Startup.cs looks like this: https://github.com/affableashish/party-invites/blob/master/Startup.cs

Comment: Hi @AshK,I have also test your project.It works well.May be you need to repair your vs.

Answer (score 2):

Change the  `_ViewImports.cshtml` file to contain the following:

```
@using YouApplicationName
@using YouApplicationName.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```